# CouchBase NOSQL announced JOIN support. What are the disadvantages to use them?

Tags: mongodb, join, couchbase, sql++, nosql

I always assumed that NoSQL (Cassandra, CouchDB, Couchbase, MongoDB, etc.) is document oriented (NO JOIN). The typical sentence: "*If you need JOIN, use the SQL database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.)"*

But now, Couchbase announced N1QL (Developer Preview 4) with JOIN support:

http://blog.couchbase.com/introducing-developer-preview-for-couchbase-server-4.0

Try it online:

http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#42

So, I am confusing. Couchbase is the first NOSQL database with JOIN support? Are there any disadvantages in using it? Why the others NOSQL database (like mongodb, couchdb, cassandra, etc.) did not implement it?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, several NoSQL databases use a JSON document model (e.g. Couchbase, MongoDB). However, document-oriented does not have to mean "NO JOINs". RDBMSs like PostgreSQL and MySQL expect you to disassemble your objects into flat tables for writing, and to use JOINs to reassemble your objects for reading. This is called the impedance mismatch.

JSON document databases can store full objects directly, so there is no impedance mismatch. However, objects often have relationships to other objects, and you need to query across those relationships. For example, Movies and Actors are related objects, and if you wanted to list Movie details along with how many awards its Actors have won, you would need a JOIN.

In summary, RDBMSs like PostgreSQL and MySQL have an impedance mismatch, so you must use JOINs for both object assembly and relationships. JSON document databases that do not have JOINs do not allow you to query across relationships, so you must implement this logic in your application, using multiple queries. Finally, a JSON document database that also provides JOINs, gives you the benefits of both: (1) there is no impedance mismatch and no disassembly / assembly, and (2) you can query across relationships between objects. That is why Couchbase is providing JOINs in N1QL.

There is no reason to have a disadvantage when using JOINs in Couchbase. JOINs are very useful when used for the right reason (relationships), and the Couchbase data model (JSON) allows you to avoid "bad" JOINs (for impedance mismatch and assembly / disassembly).

Answer (score 0):

Nicely put the from the impedance mismatch perspective